# Best way to create new Magento 2 theme based on Luma, which parent theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.0, magento-2.1, luma-theme

I am having a theme made for Magento 2 and the developer wishes to use Luma as the parent theme to keep the styling like Luma for all elements not changed in our design.

I also plan on regularly updating Magento 2 to latest versions as new bugs are fixed and wish to keep upgrade issues to a minimum.

Previously I read from the Magento team that Luma should not be used as a parent theme and only use Magento Blank, but now I see they say it is ok.

Would it be better to:

1) Use Luma as parent theme and create child theme for all our changes?

or...

2) Clone the Luma theme to our new child theme (use Magento Blank as parent) and make all changes to our new child theme?

Comment: The best answer is probably in the documentation itself :
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_overview.html At paragraph :
Why do you need to create a custom theme?

Answer (score 1):

Hello as per my experience. We're using Magento Blank as our parent theme.

We're using porto theme for magento 2. and this theme's parent is Magento Blank.

Here's a part code of the porto theme.xml

```
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
</media>
```

I hope this helps you in choosing what to use as parent. but also you can use Luma as your parent theme. It's up to you.

Comment: You can also refer in this link: https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/theming-in-magento-2-part-1

Answer (score 1):

1) Use Luma as parent theme and create child theme for all our changes?

Luma is also a child of blank. So unless you use part or all of LUMA theme features then it's Ok to use Luma theme.

**However if your new theme is different to Luma then use Blank Theme as parent. I don't see any advantage of coping Luma theme. Just create new child theme and apply your changes as you go**

Comment: Thanks for the help!  My new theme uses a similar layout as Luma theme but the header, colors and some other elements are different. The my account, shopping cart and checkout pages will be nearly identical to Luma, except for some CSS changes for colors.

I am mostly concerned with theme compatibility when upgrading Magento2 and site speed.  I am assuming site would perform better with only 1 parent / 1 child rather than 1 parent / 2 childs, that is why I suggested cloning Luma to our custom child theme (using Blank as parent) and remove unused classes for elements that are no longer used.

Comment: Developer said he could do it this way as I suggested or use Luma as parent like he originally suggested. I am just trying to decide on the best, most professional way of doing it.  I want to do it right to avoid future issues.

Comment: To my knowledge site performance is not an issue if you have cache turned on.  css, models, blocks are compiled when you go to Production Mode so it's not going to be an issue having a child of Luma