# Should I use Blank or Luma as a parent theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to create a custom theme for Magento 2 and I am curious if it is a good idea to use Luma as a parent theme or not.

I did some research and found out that Blank theme is supposed to be used for creating custom themes. But I also read that Magento changed their statement about Luma, at the beginning they stated that Luma is created for demo purposes and not for theming and now they came back on that statement.

Luma has some good benefits e.g. collapsible layered navigation and some other improvements.

I want to use Luma as a parent but I want to know if it's a good idea. I can imagine it could be better to clone and rename luma and use Blank as a parent or not use Luma at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to create new Magento 2 theme based on Luma, which parent theme?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130900/best-way-to-create-new-magento-2-theme-based-on-luma-which-parent-theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion use luma theme as parent and implement a twitter bootstrap style responsive grid system and overwrite as much as you can.

Luma is missing a decent grid system but has mostly everything else you need

My only gripe with m2 from the very start is the use of knockout. It has benefits but these are offset by the amount of time it adds clearing out and generating content after having to clear local storage when working on the checkout for example. The less you use knockout in your theme the simpler you will make your life which ultimately means a more streamlined development process. Just be wary of how your theme works with a proxy cache like varnish.

At times I've spent an hour or two trying to figure out how to change the layout or alter content of something that is loaded dynamically via knockout. No framework should be this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blank theme if you want to design theme from initial level with your requirement.

If you don't want to waste your time then you can use Luma theme. magento has developed Luma theme for demo purpose. User can easily understood how to develop theme and how to use things in theme. Luma theme's parent theme is Blank theme so indirectly we use Blank theme. We can access both theme.